# It creates an array in C, What happen when come out of the program in the memory?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

i have this doubt, You supose have an array with one billion of elements and you create the array as follows:

```
int array[1000] = {1,2, ..., n.}
```

and you finish the program.

not being like java where the machine java garbage collection the memory clean records about stored of this arrangement.
**They stay in memory or released?**

Comment: It should be fairly easy to try this out and see - although probably not with an array with one billion entry...

Answer (score 4):

When the process exits, the operating system frees all memory that the process was using.

(This does not apply to certain small embedded operating systems.)

Comment: sure, the OS reclaims the memory. But depend of the OS.

Comment: @PaqcoSuarex: That's what I said.  "This does not apply to certain small embedded operating systems."

Answer (score 1):

The memory of a program is managed by the operating system so it will get released in any case when the program quits.

In any case you're allocation, as it is written, could be

- static and outside of any function (so it won't get managed on heap like it would happen in Java), it is not really allocated neither deallocated
- automatic on stack (which is dynamic indeed but it is not how it is done in Java anyway) and it is released when it exits its scope

A real comparison would be something like

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
```

This would reside in memory until a `free(array)` is called or program quits.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this

```
if (true) {
  int array[1000] = {1,2,3};
  //...
}

// array[1000] "freed" here.
```

Then the memory will be freed when you exit the "if" braces.  This is because the memory resides on the stack and an "allocation" is just movement of the stack pointer.  When the scope exits, the stack pointer is returned to where it was before the scope was entered.  So in this case, allocation and deallocation is pretty much free (performance wise), assuming your stack is big enough to hold an additional 1000 integers.  On some embedded systems, it won't be, and your app will crash.

Same goes for

```
int foo( int x )
{
  int array[1000] = {1,2,3};
  // ...
  return array[0];
}

// array[] "freed" here.
```

Edit: in the last case, if you replace foo() with main, then the array will be "freed" when the program exits.

Comment: i think what the question refers to is arrays with block scope of main(). maybe you can edit your answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally OS will not allow you to have `int a[10000000000000000000]`.
2. Their values stay in memory.  But the memory will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the memory will be released at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

In c, If you define array like a[1000] then it will allocate in stack part and it will automatically free the memory as program exist. But if you dynamically allocate (by using malloc) then you have to use free(array) for freeing the memory. 
Maximum size of your array depends on your system RAM size.

Comment: This is the closest answer but not quite correct.  In the case of allocating on the stack, this always occurs within a context (like a function or even within an if(){} ) and the "stack" will be returned as soon as the context returns (the end of the if case or the function.)  The reason some OS' don't like big arrays like this is because they cause stack overflows - the stack for embedded systems is sometimes <1k per task.  So yes the memory will be released when the program returns, but ALSO when the context returns.  Also, maximum size of array (for malloc()) depends on heap size.

Comment: even with heap allocation(or dynamic allocation), modern OSes do claim back the memory as soon as the process terminates.(assuming array to be local to main()) although c standard does not mention of such guarantees.

Comment: even with max size of ram how can 1 billion `int`(3.7gb) in contiguous memory be guaranteed?this is highly impossible in most scenario. i think supercomputers are designed for this